# XMPP with TLS implementation

Tags: php, xml, ssl, xmpp, starttls

How can I connect to XMPP server over TLS? I've read both the book and the RFC doc about it and the instructions are clear on the high overview, but I'm missing details.

I am constructing my [own XMPP library](https://packagist.org/packages/norgul/xmpp-php) and once I open the socket to the client on port 5222 I am sending initial XML to start the conversation followed by:

```
<starttls xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
```

Server responds with:

```
<proceed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls'/>
```

After this it get's unclear about what should I do, as supposedly somehow the TLS magic should happen here, getting the server to send the certificate to the client. How is that done, and how do I know it is received?

After that the documents say that the stream should be terminated, and another one started...does that mean that I need to disconnect the socket or just close the stream by sending `</stream:stream>`?

Comment: I suggest you look at how other clients are doing it. Enable console / debug mode on an existing client and check the flow. It should guide you in how to interpret the spec.

Comment: I did download other library and trying to do so, but I can't believe there is no detailed resource on how to do this, I mean, how did they implement it if they had no idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution to the problem. My mistake was that after I got the `<proceed>` I was closing the socket in order to switch it to port `443`, change the protocol, and other similar stuff.

The solution was not to close the connection, but rather enabling crypto on existing connection by using:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->socket->connection, 
                            true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv23_CLIENT);
```

And then opening the communication once again with

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<stream:stream to=.....
```

After that you will get back the "real" response about how you can authenticate (i.e. PLAIN).

It is all implemented within [my library](https://github.com/Norgul/xmpp-php) so you can check it out.